# Error when I try to generate a libgdx projet

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to do a project on android studio with libgdx but I have a problem when I generate a libgdx project.
At first, he told me that my local variable JAVA_HOME had a problem and he could findn't my JDK (that was present)
When I tried to copy my java JDK on my file "c:\dev\java\JDK", he told me :

```
Generating app in C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\YoloRPG
Executing 'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\YoloRPG/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
Unzipping C:\Users\Thomas\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-
all\5b6kqrscumh9p4evkkemdk57ad\gradle-2.10-all.zip to 
C:\Users\Thomas\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\5b6kqrscumh9p4evkkemdk57ad
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
... 3 more
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
```

And when I try to open the created project on android with
files --> import settings...
A message box popup with written
"Cannot find file 'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\YoloRPG\settings.jar'"

Can someone please help me ?  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

This mean that a file that Gradle has downloaded has become corrupted due to somehow or some reason.
This might be the download of Gradle itself (which the wrapper does), or any dependency that Gradle has downloaded to run your libgdx build.

Gradle doesn't attempt to detect or resolve the problem, so you need to fix it manually. The solution is often to purge Gradle's download caches and let it get fresh copies of what it needs.

To do that, delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.

In your case home directory is

```
C:\Users\Thomas\.gradle
```

and Project's root directory

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\YoloRPG
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used a similar methode to solve my problem.
I went to :
`c:\Users\Thomas\.gradle\wrapper\dist`

and deleted the file
`gradle-2.10-all`

then I tiped in google chrome
    http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
and pasted the zip file where gradle-2.10-all was

Then when I retried, it downloading a corect version of gradle and it worked !

But when I try to import the libgdx project on android studio I still have the message :

```
Cannot find file 'Cannot find file 'C:\dev\libgdx projects\YoloRPG\settings.jar'
```

I'm using android studio 2.2.3, and on all the tutorials I checked, they all have a button "import non android studio project", but I only have "import settings...", do you know how I can import a libgdx on android studio now ?

Answer (score 0):

go to `androidStudioProjects/yourProject/gradle/wrapper`
open **gradle-wrapper properties** file

in last line:
(change in this line)
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip`

change in: `/gradle-2.2-all.zip` with your version
eg: in my case i replaced with
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: Can you please add more info about what was the problem and how you fixed it?

Comment: I generate a project using libgdx, when I opened that project in Android studio . The error was zip file not open message.. same error as mentioned in question.. and I fixed it in the way I mentioned above.