# Robolectric 3.8 java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I'm trying to upgrade my android project to sdk 27 and so I tried to upgraded robolectric to 3.8. Now I'm hanging on that error when I try to run my tests:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at org.robolectric.res.Fs$JarFs.<init>(Fs.java:96)
at org.robolectric.res.Fs.fromJar(Fs.java:27)
at org.robolectric.internal.SdkEnvironment.createRuntimeSdkResourcePath(SdkEnvironment.java:31)
at org.robolectric.internal.SdkEnvironment.getSystemResourceTable(SdkEnvironment.java:22)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:332)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:245)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at org.robolectric.res.Fs$JarFs.<init>(Fs.java:94)
... 27 more
```

I think the interesting part of my gradle looks like that:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
  }
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
}
```

I already tried to clean my dependencies and deleting my gradle wrapper. I appreciate every tip you can give me, ty. If you need more information to be able helping me just ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.(from:[Error when I try to generate a libgdx projet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090713/error-when-i-try-to-generate-a-libgdx-projet))

Comment: kindly conisder adding more infomation

Answer (score 1):

Delete the cache files in your maven cache. eg. my directory

`~/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all/8.1.0-robolectric-4611349`